# Rexster visualization not enabled by default?

Tags: visualization, titan, rexster

I was going by the Rexster wiki https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/The-Dog-House - 
there seems to be a visualization button available out of the box.

But when i start up with version 2.6 - I can't find it anywhere.I can browse vertices and edges though. 
Looking at the documentation it doesn't seem to be an extension point. What am i missing?

I am aware of other visualization tools like Gephi, Sigma , D3 etc and I can potentially use them.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: using Chrome-latest.

Answer (score 0):

I mis-read your question to some degree.  There have been no significant changes to Dog House in many versions to account for a break and it works in Chrome for me so it would seems that you might just not be noticing the "visualize" button.  When browsing vertices of a graph, clicking the magnifying glass icon next to a vertex or edge will launch the visualizer in an ego-centric method where that vertex and all its neighbors are displayed.